# How do I default to "*.*" instead of "Plain Text" in visual studio code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I create a new file I use Ctrl + n, so when I save the file I use Ctrl + s, the save as type defaults to: `Plain text (*.txt,*.gitignore)`

So I keep accidentally saving my files as `file.js.txt` instead of `file.js.

How do I change it to selecting `All files (*.*)` by default in the save file dialogue so that doesn't happen?

Comment: Can't you use Shift+Ctrl+s to 'save as' and then save your file as file.js.  You only neeed to do this the first time you save a particular file. After that you can use crtl+s.

Comment: You should also mention which OS you are on, as this may be OS specific. @ScottR

Comment: I'm on Windows, but it'd be good to set it for all if possible.

Comment: Hm what windows version are you using and what VS Code version? Because for me it saves it as file.js event if the filetype is Plain Text.

Comment: Maybe it helps if you turn `Windows Explorer > View > File Name Extensions` on but I doubt it because I tested it with both on and of.

Comment: Plain text being the default is annoying, but I can't reproduce VSC forcefully adding `.txt` extension. I only get `.txt` if I don't specify any extension.

Comment: As @HolyBlackCat said you will only get `.txt` files if you do not specify any extension. When writting your file name you should write `.js` expplicitly. Even if you achieve to add `All files (*.*)` by default this will not solve your problem because you will need to write `.js` anyway.

Answer (score 6):

Just set the `defaultLanguage` in the `settings.json`.

1. Click on the `File`.
2. Click on the `Preferences`.
3. Click on the `Settings`.

or just shortcut `CTRL + ,`

4. Find the `files.defaultLanguage` property.
5. Enter the prefered language.

[image]

or click the `Copy to Settings`, and then add the file type in the right pane. such as :

`"files.defaultLanguage": "javascript" // or "batch" - to set it as "."`

6. Save it (`CTRL + S`)

Comment: The question is to default to `*.*`. This answer sets the default to JavaScript.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I get it. Enter a `batch`  instead of the `javascript` and you will get what you want.

Answer (score -1):

if you dont need to change default extensions for files, you can easy save your files like you need, using "File->Save AS" option, choosing "*.*" like you need, and make any name with any extension...

as sample http://prntscr.com/okfr9s